# app crashing while I try to tweet

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using `SA_OAuthTwitterController` api for integrating twitter. While I try to post the tweet using

```
[_engine sendUpdate:tweetTextField.text]
```

my app crashes.   I am getting the error:

> Authenicated for (null).

Also My stack after crash shows me:**OAMutableURL Request URL encoded string**. what the problem ?

Comment: It seems like you aren't logged in when you are tweeting?

Comment: so do you mean I should accept answer even if I never got any ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the limited amount of information given it seems that no user has been authenticated. You may authenticate the user with a different instance of _engine which would be causing a crash.

and also may your URL not encoded with string here bellow some characters encode code define in bellow link after use this code in your URL if special characters are use...

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

and also for encode the NSURL just use bellow code...

```
NSString* escapedUrlString =
   [unescapedString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:
                        NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

hope,this help you...
:)